# Не знаю как вызвать добавление в Лэйла в Виджет Окна Диалога (живой поиск) Kivy, Python

Tags: python, sql, kivy, текст, search

Пытаюсь сделать поиск в KivyMD + Kivy. При вызове диалогового окна, появляются TextFields  в которых вводятся данные, данные забираются и через базу данных выводится список на Виджет. Виджет расширяется и заполняется лейблами. Вот проблема:
Не могу вызвать дополнение Лэйбла в виджет. Дело в том, что текстовые поля находятся в 1 классе, а вызвать добавление Лэйблов я могу толь в другом. Как это исправить?
'''

```
import sqlite3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass
class CustomToolbar(ThemableBehavior, RectangularElevationBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    pass
class OneLineListItems(OneLineListItem):
    pass
class ContentDialog(MDBoxLayout):
    textCompany = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

def insert_text(self, *args):
    self.max_characters = 2
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('tikers.db')
    self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()
    # self.con.create_function("mylower", 1, self.lower_string)
    dat = []
    if len(self.textCompany.text) > self.max_characters and self.max_characters > 0:
        tC1 = self.textCompany.text
        t1 = tC1[0:3]
        self.cursorObj.execute(f"SELECT * FROM tiks WHERE company LIKE '%{t1}%'")
        rows = self.cursorObj.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            dat.append(row)
        for id, company in dat:
            App.get_running_app().addLabel()
    self.cursorObj.close()
    self.con.close()

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Contentin = ContentDialog()
        self.load_kv('icons.kv')  # Подключаем файл kv
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('bas.db')
        self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()

dialog = None

    # Функция build
def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"  # "Purple", "Red"
    self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A400"

def showConfirmationDialog(self):
    if not self.dialog:
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9),
            title="Введите данные: ",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=ContentDialog(),

        )

    self.dialog.open()

        # Закрытие диалогового окна
def callback(self, *args):
    self.dialog.dismiss()

def addLabel(self):
    self.label = MDLabel(text=f"{company}", color=(0, 0, 0, 1))
    self.root.ids.listDialog.add_widget(self.label)
    self.label.texture_update()
    boxlayout = self.root.ids.listDialog()
    height = 0
    for child in boxlayout.children:
        height += child.texture_size[1]
        height += 2 * child.padding_y
        boxlayout.height = height

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()

kv file
<ContentDialog>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "7dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "340sp"

textCompany: textF_1

BoxLayout:
    id: listDialog
    orientation: "horizontal"
    height: "0"
    size_hint: None, None

MDTextFieldRect:
    id: textF_1
    hint_text: "ммммм"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "30sp"
    on_focus: root.insert_text()

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: "1sp"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: button_2
        size_hint: .5, None
        text :"Отмена"
        text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_color
        on_press : app.callback()
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: button_3
        size_hint: .5, None
        text: "Ввод"
        text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_color
        on_release: app.callback()
        on_press: root.insert_text()
        
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

MDToolbar:
    title: "ZaAkcii"
    right_action_items: [["clock", lambda x: app.callback_2()]]

MDTabs:
    tab_bar_height: "15dp"
    elevation: 7
    Tab:
        text:"nnnnnnnnn"

        BoxLayout:
            id: listStocks
            orientation: "vertical"
            CustomToolbar:
                id: toolbar
                pos_hint: {"bottom": 1}
                size_hint_y: None
                height: "40dp"
                padding: "5dp"
                spacing: "12dp"
                elevation: 10
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    id: button_1
                    icon: "git"
                    user_font_size: "25sp"
                    elevation_normal: 7
                    on_press: app.showConfirmationDialog()

            ScrollView:
                id: scroll
                MDList:
                    id: container

    Tab:
        text: "nnnnnn"

    Tab:
        text: "bbbbbbbb"
   
'''
```

Comment: сделал через базу данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал через базу данных. но уперся в невозможность добавлять виджеты в виджет, который находится в диалоговом окне. Решил все сделать на отдельной вкладке.
Сделал вызов новой базы данных после получения среза из TextField. В другом классе подключаюсь к БД и забираю результаты. Функцию вызываю сразу после закрытия БД.